# Navbar Horizontal Menu positioning help. Very basic

Tags: html, css

apologies for basic-ness of question, just creating a dropdown menu and having some problems with the margins and positioning.

Ive set the div of it as 85% but i want that centered in the page,
And then the list items centered in the middle of that so it's all neat but can't get it too.

```
<div class="menu-wrap">
<nav class="menu">
    <ul class="clearfix">
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li> 
        <li><a href="#">Second Page</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Third Page<span class="arrow">&#9660;</span></a>
            <ul class="sub-menu">
                <li><a href="#">Dropdown One</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Dropdown Two</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Fourth Page</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Fifth Page<span class="arrow">&#9660;</span></a>
            <ul class="sub-menu">
                <li><a href="#">Dropdown 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Dropdown Item 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Dropdown 3</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Dropdown 4</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>

    </ul>
</nav>
```

CSS:

```
.clearfix:after {
display:block;
clear:both;
}

.menu-wrap ul {
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
}

.menu-wrap {
    width:80%;
    background: #85D2CD;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: auto;
}

.menu {
    width:100%;
    margin:0px auto;
}

.menu li {
    margin:0px;
    list-style:none;
}

.menu a {
    transition:all linear 0.15s;
    color:#FFF;
}
    .menu > ul > li {
    float:left;
    display:inline-block;
    position:relative;
    font-size:19px;
}

.menu > ul > li > a {
    padding:10px 30px;
    display:inline-block;
    text-shadow:0px 1px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
    text-decoration:none;
} 
.menu > ul > li:hover > a {      /* Hover background color */
    background:#5D9390;
}

.menu li:hover .sub-menu {
    opacity:1;
}

.sub-menu {
    width: 100%;
    padding:5px 0px;
    position:absolute; /* Need this so menu height doesnt extend to dropdown       size*/
    top:100%;
    left:0px;
    z-index:-1;
    opacity:0;
    transition:opacity linear 0.15s;
    background:#6D9E9B; 
}

.sub-menu li {
    display:block;
    font-size:16px; 
}

.sub-menu li a {
    padding:10px 30px;
    display:block;
    text-decoration:none;
}

.sub-menu li a:hover {
    background:#5D9390;
}
```

I think that is the only relevant code needed, I've kinda lost my mind a bit and put margin auto in too many spots to try fix this but none of it is working

Comment: jsFiddle is showing strange things with your code: http://jsfiddle.net/d8sstx6t/

Comment: Sorry i added the full CSS now was just trying to save space @Jordumus

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all change the

```
.menu-wrap {
width: 80%;
background: #85D2CD;
display: block;
margin: 0 auto;
overflow: hidden;
}
```

And to center your menu items, change the ul style to

```
ul.sub-menu {
 text-align: center;
}
```

That should get the things sorted out and be aligned in middle.

Comment: thanks for that @brance, how come overflow: hidden is needed? If i don't have it the background color disappears, can you just explain why?

Comment: It is because you have floating elements inside that DIV, and if you want the parent elements of floating elements to have a height, that matches the children, you need to put the property overflow:hidden; on the parent element, if not the height will be 0 thus no background.

Comment: my only problem is now, when i hover over the lists with dropdowns they dont show? @brance

Comment: Oh your code is somewhat complicated, I didn't see the floating of li's, just remove float:left; from .menu > ul > li and it will work. As you already have specified display:inline-block, you don't need the additional floats. And remove the overflow: hidden; property from the .menu-wrap

Comment: Ahh, Great thanks again @brance, Do i need both the Div class menu wrap and the nav class menu? Can i just do it all without menu wrap and use Menu?

Comment: I would leave it like that, better to have more "wrappers" around your elements, they can come handy afterwards, if you need to do some customization, etc.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the width of the wrapping div, you can do this:

```
.menu-wrap{
    left: 10%;
    position: relative;
 }
```

If you get rid of the `float:left`, you can add this to the menu, to center the menu:

```
.menu {
      text-align: center;
}
```

JsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/d8sstx6t/2/

Answer (score 0):

If you don't know the width and the height of the content you can use display: table;

```css
.clearfix:after {
display:block;
clear:both;
}

.menu-wrap ul {
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
}

.menu-wrap {
    width:80%;
    background: #85D2CD;
    display: table;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.menu {
    display: table;
    margin:0 auto;
}

.menu li {
    margin:0px;
    list-style:none;
}

.menu a {
    transition:all linear 0.15s;
    color:#FFF;
}
    .menu > ul > li {
    float:left;
    display:inline-block;
    position:relative;
    font-size:19px;
}

.menu > ul > li > a {
    padding:10px 30px;
    display:inline-block;
    text-shadow:0px 1px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
    text-decoration:none;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu-wrap">
<nav class="menu">
    <ul class="clearfix">
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li> 
        <li><a href="#">Second Page</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Third Page<span class="arrow">&#9660;</span></a>
            <ul class="sub-menu">
                <li><a href="#">Dropdown One</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Dropdown Two</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Fourth Page</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Fifth Page<span class="arrow">&#9660;</span></a>
            <ul class="sub-menu">
                <li><a href="#">Dropdown 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Dropdown Item 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Dropdown 3</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Dropdown 4</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>

    </ul>
</nav>
```